# Getting Smarty errors on new 2.2.14 install

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to install version 2.2.14 on a new LAMP server. However, on the first Setup page I am getting the error:

```
include(/home/mysite/public_html/core/cache/setup/smarty/a2b9296b2cd7b74ba799b1e2f585cb6d0e3eb1d8.file.language.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mysite/public_html/core/model/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php on line 422
```

I have tried opening up permissions for all the files in smarty to no avail.

I am really not sure what to do or how to fix this. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that for whatever reason I was unable to delete the `core` directory - even with FTP. This was causing conflicts. I renamed it to `coreOLD` and tried again and it works. Weird.